# QT C++ download multiple files with progress total

Tags: c++, qt, download, qfile

I realized downloading multiple files, but I don't know how to implement the total progress bar of the download, that is common.

My code:

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QList<QNetworkReply *> currentDownloads;

void MainWindow::checkUpdate()
{
        QStringList files;
        files << "http://cavexp.net/uploads/game/Theugry/zips/resourcepacks.zip"
              << "http://cavexp.net/uploads/game/Theugry/zips/resourcepacks.zip";

        doDownload(files);
}

void MainWindow::doDownload(const QVariant& v)
{
    if (v.type() == QVariant::StringList) {
        foreach (QString url, v.toStringList()) {
            QNetworkReply* reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));

            connect(&manager, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)),
                this, SLOT(updateDownloadProgress(qint64, qint64)));

            currentDownloads.append(reply);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    currentDownloads.removeAll(reply);
    reply->deleteLater();
}

void MainWindow::updateDownloadProgress(qint64 bytesRead, qint64 totalBytes)
{
    ui->progressBar->setMaximum(totalBytes);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(bytesRead);
}
```

I would be grateful for any help and hints! Thank you.

Comment: manager has no signal `downloadProgress` isn't it, maybe you mean just `reply` `connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)),this, SLOT(updateDownloadProgress(qint64, qint64)));`?

Comment: @Chernobyl I do not know how to implement it. Can you show a working example? I would be very grateful!

Comment: @Chernobyl по-русски грамотнее объясню. Реализовано скачивание файлов, хочу вывести общий прогресс их скачивания.

Comment: @John перевожу на русский то, что сказал Chernobyl: у класса QNetworkAccessManager (смотрим здеся: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) нет сигнала, который бы сообщал прогресс. Сначала нужно у этого менеджера попросить QNetworkReply с помошью функции get(), а у того уже такой сигнал есть. Смотрим пример тута - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-downloadmanager-downloadmanager-cpp.html (ищем строку currentDownload = manager.get(request); )

Comment: @mvidelgauz спасибо, но в этом примере показывается именно прогресс для 1 файла. Как реализовать общий прогресс бар скачивания нескольких файлов? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to iterate over your 'currentDownloads' list and connect to each one's signal [downloadProgress](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#downloadProgress). Then your slot(s) will be called from all of them. In that slot(s) you'll have to sum up all information coming as parameters of QNetworkReply::downloadProgress signal.

You can create a dedicated object for each QNetworkReply instance of your currentDownloads list so that you know from to which file a coming signal belongs, but if I am not mistaking you can also use single slot for all of them and then there is a meta function in Qt that will tell you from which sender the signal came.

P.S. In response to your request for small example here is "straight-forward" approach (without using QSignalMapper or QObject::sender()):

Implement a class "ProgressListenner" something like this (beware I am writing pseudo-code and you'll need to add/fix some necessarily stuff to make it actually working):

```
class ProgressListenner
{
   public:
   ProgressListenner() : _lastKnownReceived(0), _lastKnownTotal(0){}

   qint64 _lastKnownReceived;
   qint64 _lastKnownTotal;

   slots:
      onDownloadProgress ( qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal )
      {
          _lastKnownReceived = bytesReceived;
          _lastKnownTotal = bytesTotal;
      }
}
```

Than after your line `QList<QNetworkReply *> currentDownloads;` add `QList<ProgressListenner*> downloadListenners;`. Inside your `foreach` each time you are adding new `QNetworkReply` object to `currentDownloads` also:
1. create new instance of `ProgressListenner` and add it to `downloadListenners`. 
2. connect signal of that particular QNetworkReply to that corresponding ProgressListenner's slot: `connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), pListenner, SLOT(onDownloadProgress (qint64, qint64)));`

This way every time some QNetworkReply will fire it's progress signal, slot of corresponding ProgressListenner will be called.

Next step is sum up numbers from all downloads. One simple way is:
1. Create one more function in `ProgressListenner` class and make it `static` (important). Let say the name of function is `CommonProgress`.
2. At the end of `onDownloadProgress` function call also call `CommonProgress`
3. In `CommonProgress` function (taking care about thread safety!) iterate over all elements of `downloadListenners` and sum up their `_lastKnownReceived` and `_lastKnownTotal`. Do the necessarily arithmetic... Don't forget that `bytesTotal` can be -1!!!

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись! Если честно, не представляю как это реализовать. Вы можете показать небольшой пример? Я был бы очень благодарен!

Thank you for your help! To be honest, no idea how to implement it. Can you show a small example? I would be very grateful!

Comment: @John I have added some pseudo-code to my answer. Let me know if you need more explanation...

Comment: в очередной раз спасибо, но я понял лишь отчасти, было бы очень замечательно если бы вы рассказали бы более подробнее. once again thank you, but I realized only partially, it would be very nice if you would tell more in detail.

Comment: Если Вам будет удобнее, то я могу скинуть весь проект. If You want, I can throw the whole project.

Comment: Скинте на michael@videlgauz.com, хотя мне кажется, что это противоречит правилам этого сайта. В любом случае, без самостоятельной работы Вам не обойтись )))